# Innosetup SendMessage after changing the environment values

Tags: winapi, casting, inno-setup

I set environment variable in the registry using InnoSetup:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MY_PROGRAM_HOME_DIR"; ValueData: "{app}"
```

But system cannot see this variable until I call `SendMessage`.

```
[Code]
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  // HWND_BROADCAST = $FFFF 
  // WM_SETTINGCHANGE = $001A
  SendMessage($FFFF, $001A, 0, Longint(PChar('Environment')));
end;
```

InnoSetup says:

> ... Column 60: Type mismatch

How do I correctly typecast `PChar` into `Longint` in InnoSetup script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ChangesEnvironment`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_changesenvironment) directive instead of doing the same from your script code. From the reference:

> When set to yes, at the end of the installation Setup will notify
>   other running applications (notably Windows Explorer) that they should
>   reload their environment variables from the registry.

In InnoSetup, when you use the above directive, the following code is called inside:

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
  LPARAM(PChar('Environment')), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, MsgResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use the ChangesEnvironment

Work fine for me.

Ex:

```
[Setup]
ChangesEnvironment=yes
```

Be careful:
The broadcast message occur before the call of 'DeinitializeSetup'