# How to notify Python from an Inno Setup that the environment path has changed?

Tags: python-2.7, installation, inno-setup, pascal

So I'm trying to create an installer that has the following steps:

1. Check if Python is installed
2. Copy my app files
3. Check if the Python install directory is in the Windows Environment Path
4. Check if the Python scripts folder is in the Windows Environment Path
5. **If the scripts folder is not in the env path, add it**
6. **install easy_install**
7. **run a python script that uses easy_install to install several libraries**

The problem is encountered in the last few steps. Here is the relevant code for the Inno setup I am currently using:

```
begin
  case CurStep of
     ssInstall:       // File transfer is about to begin.
     begin
        // Note: Use abort(); to terminate the install during this step.
     end;

ssPostInstall:   // File transfer has finished.
  begin
     // Make sure Python is in the path.
     sPythonInstallDir := _PythonGetInstallDir();
     _PathAddToSystem( sPythonInstallDir )
     _PathAddToSystem( sPythonInstallDir + 'Scripts;' )

     // Run the bundled Python script.
     ExtractTemporaryFile( 'build_setup_script.py' );
     ExtractTemporaryFile( 'ez_setup.py'           );
     _LaunchApp( AddQuotes( sPythonInstallDir + 'python.exe' ), AddQuotes( ExpandConstant( '{tmp}\build_setup_script.py' ) ), ExpandConstant( '{tmp}' ), SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, 300, nTime, nResultCode );
  end;

ssDone :         // After the Finish dialog.
  begin
  end;
end;
```

here is the python script:

```
def main(argv):
   ## Easy Install
   print("Installing easy_install")
   call(["Python", "ez_setup.py"])
...
   ## Installs server.py dependencies
   print("\nInstalling SQLAlchemy")
   call(["easy_install", "SQLAlchemy==0.7.8"])
...
```

In the inno setup I also have the following directive

```
[Setup]
...
ChangesEnvironment=true
...
```

however, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550791/innosetup-sendmessage-after-changing-the-environment-values), the directive only takes effect after the user clicks finish.

So the setup appends to the path:

```
...C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

but, then the script runs (which works because inno seems to be aware that the path has changed and can execute Python files) the script will then install easy_install, which works for some reason, but when it tries to use easy_install (which is why the C:Python\Scripts; is in the path) it throws a file not found exception.

However, when I run the installer a second time, without making any changes, the easy_install steps will then work because now when Python runs, it can detect the path to easy_install.

I figure there has to be a way to notify processes prior to clicking finish, however copying the code in the aforementioned [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550791/innosetup-sendmessage-after-changing-the-environment-values) doesn't even compile in inno

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, LPARAM(PChar('Environment')), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, MsgResult);
```

Asking the user to start the install a second time is out of the question since the installer should be automated in the first place... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to notify all the windows about environment changes, like does the following code (internally used by InnoSetup when the wizard is finished and the [`ChangesEnvironment`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_changesenvironment) directive is set to `yes`):

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
  LPARAM(PChar('Environment')), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, MsgResult);
```

You can use the following import (tested with most recent ANSI and Unicode versions of InnoSetup):

```
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2;
  WM_WININICHANGE = $001A;
  WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE;
type
  LONG_PTR = LongInt;
  LRESULT = LONG_PTR;  
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = LONG_PTR;

function SendTextMessageTimeout(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT;
  wParam: WPARAM; lParam: string; fuFlags: UINT; 
  uTimeout: UINT; var lpdwResult: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT;
  external 'SendMessageTimeout{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';
```

And call it like shown in this pseudo code whenever you need in your script:

```
var
  MsgResult: DWORD_PTR;
begin
  if SendTextMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
    'Environment', SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, MsgResult) <> 0
  then
    MsgBox('Success!', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: So I found out that even with notifying happening, the current running environment of Inno is still 'old' and doesn't reflect the changes, so any processes it launches inherit this 'old' environment. Anything started after the notification, but not started from inno, will see the changes however.
In the end I just passed the location of the program to the script :S